# Should I accept my own answer which I got from asking the same question on a different forum after no one on SO answered my first question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

I asked a question on SO. After a few days of no answers, I asked the same question on a different forum. I got an answer from the other forum and posted it as answer on my SO question, which still had no answers.

Credit really belongs to the guy who answered my question on the other forum (I cited him and linked to his post in my SO answer). And I don't want to anger anyone by accepting my own answer. But it also seems misleading to not accept it when I know that it's right. What should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if it's the right answer then accept it.  You won't get the rep, but it'll let people know that you found the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way, in this situation, is to answer the question yourself, and credit the guy from the other forum (i.e. link back to his profile) as much as possible.  This is the way that stackoverflow wants its answers to be represented on other sites, might as well extend other forums the same courtesy.  Also, make sure you check their attribution requirements (if applicable).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, James!